# When is the limit of the ratio of consecutive terms of a sequence algebraic given it exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Is there an eventually increasing sequence of natural numbers $(a_n)^\infty _{n=1}$ such that  $\exists k \in \mathbb{N} : \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+k}}{a_n} \notin A $, where  $ A $ denotes the set of algebraic numbers. I am expecting that this will always converge to some algebraic number yet I have failed to prove so. Can anyone provide some useful pointers on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$a_0=3,  a_n=\lfloor \pi a_{n-1} \rfloor$$
You have $a_n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to \pi$

EDIT : Proof :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n \pi-1 \leq \lfloor \pi a_n \rfloor < a_n \pi+1$$
$$ \pi -\frac{1}{a_n} \leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} <  \pi +\frac{1}{a_n}$$
and since $a_n \to \infty$ then$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to \pi$

Comment: For a_0=3;and a_1=9; pi<=9/3=3 is false.

Comment: @namen sorry, I edited

Comment: accepted, thank you very much